# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Area already instantiated for: ProjectDefault (Template) Project" Idea-SBT plugin error

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt-idea

I'm using intellij Idea 2019.2 ultimate edition. After I updated from 2019.1. 2019.2 edition I get below exception frequently.

I couldn't submit the report to SBT as the report button is always disabled.

How could I stop this exception other than disabling the plugin?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The plugin hasn't been updated in a while and has the following deprecation messaged on its [website](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5007-sbt):

> DEPRECATION JetBrains have recently added support for an SBT console
>   to the IntellIJ Scala Plugin. This is now the recommended way to use
>   SBT within IntellIJ. No new releases of this plugin are planned.
>
> Go to the "Before launch" options of a Run Configuration, uncheck
>   "Make" and choose "Run SBT Action / test-compile" to compile the
>   project with SBT. This plugin does not generate or synchronize your
>   IDEA project structure from the SBT build configuration. We recommend
>   using the native support for importing SBT in IntelliJ. For more
>   details, see:
>   http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/11/18/built-in-sbt-support-in-intellij-idea-13/

I figured I don't need it anymore and uninstalled it. This doesn't really answers you question but I don't think this issue will be solved by the plugin maintainer.